# Using Alias for Created Columns in a math equation - SQL

Tags: sql

Is it possible in SQL to use the table alias name that was created in another statement? For example:

TotalPaid was created and now I'd like to use that to get the TotalTax.

```
SELECT
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    e.Salary,
    (Salary/(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2021-01-01', CURDATE()))) AS **TotalPaid**,
    (TotalPaid*TaxRate) AS TotalTax, 
    a.StreetNumber, 
    a.StreetName,
    a.PostalCode,
    a.City, 
    a.Province,
    d.DepartmentName
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE e
JOIN 
    ADDRESS a
        ON e.AddressID = a.AddressID
JOIN
    DEPARTMENT d
        ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
JOIN
    TAX t
        ON a.Province = t.ProvinceName;
```

If I re-write the whole equation for how to get the TotalPaid, it does work.

*i.e.  ((Salary/(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2021-01-01', CURDATE())))*TaxRate) AS TotalTax*

But wondering if there is a cleaner way.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055126/using-alias-in-query-and-using-it

Comment: Not in the same `select` but there are lots of approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the order in which the SQL Statement is parsed and compiled you cannot reference a column alias in the same `select` statement, at the point where the statement is tokenised and the data to be retrieved for processing is determined, the alias does not yet exist.

Numerous workarounds exists, such as

Wrapping the first `select` in an *outer* select thus creating a *derived table*, in which your alias exists as a new column and can be referenced.

Using a `CTE` to accomplish a simiar result.

or just repeating the expression - the query optimiser will not repeat the calculation but will only do it once.