# SQL sum group by based on another field

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello assuming this query, with inner queries inside how do I use `x` and `y` in the last `sum` function

```
select  sum(....) as x, (select ...) as y...., sum( x*y) as real_answer 
from table_1
.... 
group by id,...
```

What I have been able to do without the `sum` function, this is working:

```
select .. x,...y,..., (select x) *(select y) from 
table_1.... 
group by id,...
```

but yet because of the group by I want it to enter the sum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using alias in query and using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055126/using-alias-in-query-and-using-it)

Comment: @Stu This querstion is related to definite DBMS whereas a question by your link is generic.

Comment: The explanation in the linked question's answers I believe are still relevant?